# How can you get the height of an element with height:auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the height of one element to the height of another by using javscript, and I've tried using the jquery height() method but it doesn't work because one of the element's has height set to auto:

```
#content
{
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    min-height:900px;
    height:auto;
    border-top:5px solid #032F76;
    border-bottom:5px solid #032F76;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

So is there any easy way to get the height of an element who's height is set to auto?

Comment: Are you talking about height of block itself or height of its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's .height() method **still** returns the numerical height value even if it's set to auto. BUT make sure you take margin, padding and borders into consideration.

I ran a test with your CSS just to make sure and .height() works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/ysMge/8/

jQuery has 3 height calculating functions that take the margin, padding and border values into account differently.

Please review:

```
$("#content").height()
$("#content").outerHeight()
$("#content").innerHeight()
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/
http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/
http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Comment: +1 Since OP is already using jQuery, I think this would be an obvious non-contrived way to get height.

Comment: "make sure you take margin and border into consideration", margin? you meant padding?

Comment: Fixed, all 3 actually. Margins, padding and borders.

Comment: the only thing is... I tried doing this:<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('content_right').innerHTML=$('#content').height();
</script> but it didn't return a value for height

Comment: actually.. I figured out I was calling height before the page loaded so that's why it was returning null

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getComputedStyle`:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('content');
var height = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue('height');
```

Which should return the computed height, in pixels, of the element.

A somewhat [contrived JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ju26Y/).

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```
$('#content').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a sample of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  CenterFrameSizer();
});

function CenterFrameSizer(){
  // Sets the left box and the center box the same height.
  if ( $("#leftbox").height() > $("#contentbox").height() ) {
    $("#contentbox").height($("#leftbox").height());
  } else {
    $("#leftbox").height($("#contentbox").height());
  }
}

function GalleryResize(){
  if ( $("#leftbox").height() > $("#gallery").height() ) {
    $("#gallery").height($("#leftbox").height());
  } else {
    $("#leftbox").height($("#gallery").height());
  }
}
```